# Where the E-M radiation is coming from?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

In the case of two charged spheres connected by a wire and separated by a fixed distance $d$, if the charges are changing periodically, then this system (also referred to as an electric dipole) radiates. But I wonder, is the radiation   coming from the spheres or from the wire? It occurred to me that since the spheres are not accelerating, they do not radiate, but the wire carries alternating currents, so they are supposed to radiate. Am I correct? But many calculations concerning this radiation are actually calculating the electric and magnetic fields from the spheres, why?

Comment: If there is a changing charge density, across the sphere  and a wire connecting them, there IS a current density in the sphere

Comment: but the wire carries  a changing current, thw wire should generate electric and magnetic fields,right? Or is it because the radiation from the wire is negligible compared to the spheres?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a changing charge density, across the sphere  and a wire connecting them, there IS a current density in the sphere. Charge moves from one sphere to the other  and as such there needs to be a current density inside the sphere $$\nabla \cdot \vec{J} = -\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$$ If J is zero in the sphere, there CANNOT be a changing charge density

Radiation comes from the total current in a wire and the sphere